# PHP Session is being cleared after running a script

Tags: php, session

When a user visits a certain page on my site the script below runs once.  This works perfectly, but for some reason after it runs the one time, the session is cleared and is set to "0".

The session name is "user_zip" and here is the code that is somehow clearing the session.

```
$user_zip_query = "SELECT * FROM dev_cities WHERE city_zip = '".$_SESSION['user_zip']."'";
$user_zip = mysql_query($user_zip_query);
$userziprow = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_zip);
$state = $userziprow['city_state'];
$county = $userziprow['city_county'];
$city = $userziprow['city_name'];
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

The Session is started in an included class file with this code...

```
 public function __construct() {

        include_once("includes/userconfig.php");                  // include database constants        

        if ($this->checkDatabase()) {                   // check for database connection

            session_start();                            // create session
```

Comment: This code as above does not have the capability to change a SESSION variable assignment. Please look in other lines of code

Comment: Use paste.to if the code realllly long

Comment: Here you go.  http://www.paste.to/MjE0ODUzNQ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has quotes in the session which is also surrounding by quotes which is cancelling out the session change it to this:

```
$uzip = $_SESSION['user_zip'];
//highly recommend use add SQL injecton prevention here how ever
$user_zip_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dev_cities WHERE city_zip = '$uzip'") or die(mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_zip_query);
$state = $row['city_state'];
$county = $row['city_county'];
$city = $row['city_name'];
```

Comment: It is there and the variables are being used, it's just that this one variable "user_zip" is being cleared after running the script on this page and using the variable one time.

Comment: Can you update the script showing where you have session_Start(); i feel it is been unset some where else tan that particular snippet of code :)

Comment: I updated the original post to show where session_Start() is located.  It's in an included class that is called from the beginning of all my pages.

Comment: before this query `$user_zip_query` echo the session and see if it ouputs any thing or if its not outputting anything.

Comment: Good thought.  I did it and yes the session user_zip is displayed and is accurate in that position.  Reloading the page though removed it and displays "0"

Comment: I echoed the session user_zip 'after' the snippet of code and it returned "Resource id #7".  Is there some conflict with the name of my query?

Comment: How is it setting it in the first place? Some kind form submit?

Comment: Your query is fine from what i can see. But try this for more error info:

http://www.paste.to/MjE3MzI4Mw==

Comment: @Budove add `echo 'test';` in `if ($this->checkDatabase()) {  ` then refresh if you do not see test then we know session_start(); has not occured. At least it narrows down the possible causes.

Comment: Ok, when I echo 'test' there I'm getting this output...  test
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at .../classes/Login.class.php:32) in .../classes/Login.class.php on line 33

Comment: That is expected because you echo'test'; before the session_start(); but we were just testing it so you can remove that echo now. Now after this line:

$userziprow = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_zip); echo the session user_zip... we need to find the precise line where the session becomes 0.

Comment: The echo $_SESSION['user_zip']; returns Resource id #7 after this line... $user_zip = mysql_query($user_zip_query);  It returns the correct zip just before that line

Comment: Change your code to this : http://www.paste.to/MjE3Mzc4Ng== see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yep... that fixed it!  Thank you!  Do you know what was specifically causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but i think this : ` '".$_SESSION['user_zip']."'";` needed to be in curly brackets because ['user_zip'] uses quotes... which means it closes the quotes around the entire session. so it was reading it like this:

`'".$_SESSION['` then `user_zip']."'` Which means session = 0.

Comment: Ahh.  That makes sense.  Thanks again for the help.  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

Comment: No prob :) BTW you need to add sql injection prevention for security measures on your queries :) http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: That's on the agenda before the site goes public.  I'm going to go through all the code and do it at once.  Thanks though.

Comment: No prob ! Enjoy ! And happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

to use session what we need to do is

1 start session by

The `session_start()` function must appear BEFORE the  tag:

2 Storing a Session Variable like

`$_SESSION['bla']=blabla;`

3 Destroying a Session

To delete some session data, you can use the `unset()` or the `session_destroy()` function.

**Good Read**

1. [**Session Handling**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)
2. [**PHP Security Guide: Sessions**](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html)

---

**Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)